# Rules E-mailing

Tags: nodes, rules

I am sending an email using rules after a content is created and I am trying to figure out how to have the email sent from the user that that made the content.

Answer (score 1):

In the Send Email action, there should be an option for "from". Click on "switch to data selection", then enter content:author:mail(or something along the lines of that).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Rules event "After saving a new user account."  (Note that: "Before saving a user account" is too early. No UID exists.)

Select the action "Send mail."

In the "From" value for the "Send mail" action, use the replacement variable [account:mail].

You will need the Tokens module I believe to accomplish this using this method.

---

As a side note, emails triggered from your server using the from address of your users will likely be marked as spam as they are (usually) not originating from a permitted source.